# Typescript error: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using the [Angular Material table component](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) like so:

```
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((response) => {
        this.users = new MatTableDataSource(response);
    });
```

It works but when compiling it throws the following typescript error:

> Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '{}[]'. The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did
>   you mean to use the 'any' type instead? Property 'includes' is missing
>   in type 'Object'.

So I tried changing it to:

```
this.users = new MatTableDataSource<any>(response);
```

But still same error. `response` looks like this:

```
[{
    userId: 123,
    username: 'Tom'
}, {
    userId: 456,
    username: 'Joe'
}]
```

Any idea how to get rid of the error?

**EDIT**

Should mention if I do this:

```
this.users = new MatTableDataSource([response]);
```

the error goes away but then the table doesn't work because the format isn't the right one that's expected by the table. Just noting this in case it sheds any light as to what may be the cause...

Comment: Have you tried typecasting? E.g. `response as any`

Comment: You need to change your `subscribe()` function to pass a correct (array) type to its callback parameter.

Comment: @JonasW. YES! this worked `this.users = new MatTableDataSource(<any> response);` Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'.

That does not mean that `MatTableDataSource` accepts the wrong parameter, but rather that your `response` has the wrong type. You should definetly typecast that:

```
  (response: {userId: number, username: string }[]) =>
```

or do that when passing it:

```
 new MatTableDataSource(response as {userId: number, username: string }[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `subscribe()` function needs to pass `any`:

In your case (as already indicated in the comments):

```
this.users = new MatTableDataSource(<any> response);
```

In some cases it might be like this:

```
const myLocalData = this.getData(<any> response);
```