# Angular 6 and Angular Material Mat table dataSource Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource, angular6

I am getting a list of users from a MySQL database to display it in `<mat-table>` using the `dataSource` property:

The following is the TypeScript method `getUnitData()`, where I am setting the dataSource value as the returned JSON array from PHP script:

```js
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<units>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private auth: AuthApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string){
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if(this.dataSource.paginator)
    {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  getUnitData(){
    this.auth.getUnitDataService().subscribe(
      (data)=>
      {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      },
      (error)=>
      {

      }
    )
  }

}
```

And here is the main method from the `AuthApiService`:

```js
getUnitDataService(){
    if(this.checkIsLogin){
      this.headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

      return this.http.get(this.globalVar.getUnitData,{
        headers: this.headerOptions
      });
    }
    else{
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
  }
```

The PHP script is:

```php
public function getUnitData($conn)
{
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM unit ORDER BY unit_id DESC";
        $getData = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $getDataResult = $getData->execute();
        $getDataSize = $getDataResult->rowCount();
        $getDataResult->fetchAll();

        return $getDataResult;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And then I am calling in another file using the following URL: `this.globalVar.getUnitData`.

The errors I am getting is as the following:

**1.**

> [ts] Cannot find name 'units'.

**2.**

> Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'any[]'.   The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types.
> Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Property 'length' is missing in type 'Object'.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085153/typescript-error-argument-of-type-object-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-ty?answertab=active#tab-top) on Stack Overflow, but still I get the same error.

Comment: try  `this.dataSource.data=Object.values(data)`

Comment: nope, it didn't worked. No error, but nothing changed on the DOM

Answer (score 7):

I got the same problem and I solved it through this way:

```
new MatTableDataSource(<any> response);
```

Comment: Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead. in angular8

Comment: new MatTableDataSource( response  as any);

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to create new MatTableDataSource where dataSource var is initialized,
MatPaginator and MatSort initialized in ngAfterViewInit and then in service method call  this.dataSource.data = data

```
    export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
     //  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<units>;
         dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<units>();

      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
     constructor(private auth: AuthApiService) { }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
       // add ngAfterViewInit hook
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }

     ngOnInit() {

    }

   applyFilter(filterValue: string){
     this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if(this.dataSource.paginator)
   {
    this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
   }
 }

 getUnitData(){
   this.auth.getUnitDataService().subscribe(
    (data)=>
   {
     //get data from service pass it to dataSouce.data Object
     this.dataSource.data = data;
   },
    (error)=>
    {

    }
    )
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First try to use an interface [upper camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) name to differentiate your models and variables in another file, for example, *UnitData.model.ts*:

```
//Example
export interface UnitData {
  data: string;
   number: number;
   ...
}
```

Then import the model:

```
import { UnitData } from 'src/app/models/UnitData.model';

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  units: UnitData[] = [];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<UnitData>(this.units)

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  constructor(private auth: AuthApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string){
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if(this.dataSource.paginator)
    {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  getUnitData(){
    this.auth.getUnitDataService().subscribe(
      (data)=>
      {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
      },
      (error)=>
      {

      }
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and solved it this way

```
report: any = new MatTableDataSource()
```