# Unable to pass data to MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular

I've a service which is returning a objects from an http request.

I'm trying to pass the response as the datasource input but it throws an error `Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReleasenoteData'`

I need to show the title. Please help

Response will be like below,

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "id":"203901655",
         "type":"page",
         "status":"current",
         "title":"Some Title",
         "restrictions":{  

         },
.....
```

Below is my code,

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ReleaseService } from './release.service';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'releases',
  templateUrl: './releases.component.html'
})
export class ReleasesComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Release notes';
  displayedColumns = ['releasenotes'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ReleasenoteData>;
  data:any;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor ( private releaseNotes: ReleaseService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit () {
    const data: ReleasenoteData[] = [];

     this.data = this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
    .subscribe(response => data.push(response));   
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
}

export interface ReleasenoteData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
}
```

Service:

```
  getReleaseNotes() {
      return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close to the right syntax, just a little change here:

```
this.data = this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes().subscribe(response => data.push(response));
```

Subscribe method doesn't return a `ReleasenoteData`but a subscription. 
Change it so:

```
this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes().subscribe(response => this.data.push(response.results));
```

I don't understand why you assign the service response to the local `const data` . Use `this.data`, remove `any` and set the type.

Comment: it shows `[ts] Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'.
`

Comment: your service doesn't return the response json you reported. Add details about service.

Comment: I get response like this `{results: Array(25), start: 0, limit: 25, size: 25, _links: {…}}`

Comment: I suggest you to add return type to service method `getReleaseNotes = ():Observable<ResponseType> => {
      return this.http.get(this.url);
  }`, `ResponseType` must have `results: Array<ReleasenoteData>`. Create more types and remove all `any`, to catch all conversion errors.

Comment: this isn't the result you reported above... did you learn angular from scratch?
I would recommend first to read this for explanation and then go on to observables, subscribe() and functions like map...
[link](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)

also your service method has no return type (Observable<T>)

Answer (score 0):

your response has the wrong type, your interface model only has id and title.
you need to typecast it or change your interface model so that it accepts your response.

Solution with typecasting:

```
response => data.push(new MatTableDataSource<ReleaseNoteData>(response as {id: number, title: string }))
```

Referring to this link: 
[Typescript error: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}[]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085153/typescript-error-argument-of-type-object-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-ty?rq=1)

Comment: it shows `[ts] Cannot find name 'ReleaseNoteData'.
`

Comment: you didn't import your interface ReleaseNoteData

Answer (score 0):

are you using a HTTP call in 'this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()' service? if this is the case, you might need first to 'extract' the content from the response:

```
this.releaseNotes.getReleaseNotes()
    .map((res: Response) => {
       return res.json().results || {};
     })
    .subscribe(a => data.push(a))
```

Comment: it throws an error `[ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
`

Comment: try to remove it and see. what does getReleaseNotes() return?

Comment: This is the service, it returns the response `  getReleaseNotes() {
      return this.http.get(this.url);
  }   `